# How can these two json be different?

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am using volley with android. As I am studying this example on github https://github.com/evancharlton/folly . That project made a perfect solution of querying json.

Now comes the problem. If I replace the json url there with another, then the fetching seems not to work!

I know different jsonws need different parsing jobs so I extremely simplified the code. Like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    private ViewPager pager;
    private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
    private MyPagerAdapter adapter;
    private String url = "http://konachan.com/post.json?limit=1";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        txt.setText("initial");
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                txt.setText("somethinghappend");
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                   @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.e("wtf", error.toString()) ;
                }
            });
        queue.add(jsObjRequest);


    }

}
```

As you can tell, I removed everything about the content of json but only doing this to figure out why the code goes wrong with only one change: the url

To make it clear:(i dont have enough reputation for multi links so use the comment insdead) 
when I set url to 
(comment 1)
my TextView successfully change his text(this is the json used in the example project from github, though this is meaningless information since I had built very unrelated code from the example)

but when I switch the address to
(comment 2)
nothing happen to my TextView!(this is the json I really need to work with)

And yes, both jsons are correctly fetched and parsed and displayed in firefox(without any kind of proxy), so I think there are nothing wrong with the jsons and the network.
In fact I think the ONLY difference is that they are different jsons.... with 2 different urls....

Now I seek help from you guys, how can that be? Nothing changed but only a smaller json.. makes everything broken? (is it about timeout matters? but both are loaded very fast in firefox... and obviously the working one contains much more bytes than the not working one...)

the error logged 410 error. The page has Gone?! But it is alive in firefox... and the other json works in both environment(firefox and app)

Comment: http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=96e3cd93b482b82c5acacff05d77fdab&text=android&page=1&per_page=100&format=json&nojsoncallback=1

Comment: http://konachan.com/post.json?limit=1

Comment: I suspect that `onErrorResponse` is getting called instead of `onResponse`. If so, then since you do nothing with the `error` parameter, nothing seems to be happening. Use the `error` parameter to track down where the problem lies.

Comment: Many thanks to you, Ted. I really need to establish a healthy and functional programming habit somehow... But since now I know I get a 410 instead of 200 and I consider that is because the site's considering my app as a evil robot or something. Though it was not what I asked about int the first place. Do you know anything about how to dodge this situation? I know little about faking client things. Anyway I am not a evil robot. I do not know if @TedHopp works here...

Comment: in fact 410 only means gone and the second json CAN be fetched in firefox and the first one works fine both in firefox and app... I am still very confusing about what happened, not what to do though.

Comment: From the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5): _"The 410 response is primarily intended to assist the task of web maintenance by notifying the recipient that the resource is intentionally unavailable"_. Depending on how the server is set up, the 410 may be due to security concerns triggered by headers (or missing headers) in the request coming from your app.